# Manually dummy-coded variable works but its factor version fails in a mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

In my dataset, I have created two variables from a binary factor called `name`. Specifically `Dl = as.numeric(name == "lnw")` and `De = as.numeric(name == "exper")`.

Now, when I fit ***two equivalent models***:

model `one` using `Dl` and `De` as predictors works fine. BUT:

model `two` using `name` without intercept (which is equivalent to `Dl` and `De`) as predictor throws an error.

I wonder why model `two`, despite equivalence to model `one`, fails?

```
library(nlme)

dat <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/mm.csv")

cl = lmeControl(maxIter = 200, msMaxIter = 200, niterEM = 50,
      msMaxEval = 400)

one <- lme(value ~ 0 + Dl + Dl:uerate + De + De:uerate, data = dat,
         random = ~0 + Dl + Dl:uerate + De + De:uerate | id, 
        weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | name),
        control = cl)

coef(summary(one))

#                Value   Std.Error    DF   t-value       p-value
#Dl         2.14377543 0.020444904 11913 104.85622  0.000000e+00
#De         6.85880600 0.134263638 11913  51.08461  0.000000e+00
#Dl:uerate -0.03704627 0.002194894 11913 -16.87839  3.510614e-63
#uerate:De -0.42524108 0.015484080 11913 -27.46311 4.721487e-161

two <- lme(value ~ 0 + name+ name:uerate, data = dat,
         random = ~0 + name+ name:uerate | id, 
        weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | name),
        control = cl)

#Error in lme.formula(value ~ 0 + name + name:uerate, data = swages, random = ~0 +  : 
#  nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
#  message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you alter the control paramenters in `lmecontrol` it converges:

```
cl = lmeControl(maxIter = 200, msMaxIter = 1000, niterEM = 500,
                msMaxEval = 2000)

two <- lme(value ~ 0 + name+ name:uerate, data = dat,
           random = ~0 + name+ name:uerate | id, 
           weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | name),
           control = cl)
```

Comment: Dear Robert, I was wondering if [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/518663/140365) has an answer?